# Template10 Not able to make Hamburger pane start closed. Any hints?

Tags: template10

`<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu"  IsOpen="False" />`

Doesn't do anything. What am I missing?  Its splitter starts up in the open position.

Comment: My code line isn't showing up here.  It was <Controls.HamburgerMenu x:Name=MyHamburgerMenu IsOpen="False" >

Comment: Hi, did you check the different visual states? It' normally there to look after

Comment: There were no VisualStates in a code search of the project.  They are there and set to have it be normally opened on the wide view.  I guess the question is how do I override that.  I put just now put a set of VisualStates on the HamburgerMenu page but they have the same result if I set IsOpen="False"

Comment: Just have a look on the new adaptive triggers in template10. The VisualStates are defined in the pages xaml and in the file styles/custom.cs

Comment: Thank you.  That has me on the right track.

Comment: You're welcome; glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

If you created the project using a Template10 template, you should see a Shell.xaml.cs. In there is code to get a reference to HamburgerMenu

```
public static HamburgerMenu HamburgerMenu => Instance.NMAHamburgerMenu;
```

Then in App.xaml.cs you can

```
HamburgerMenu.IsOpen = false; //close Hamburger pane
```

or
    HamburgerMenu.HamburgerButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Comment: With so little info in the question, your answer certainly seems correct to me.